# How to convert ALAC to FLAC?

Tags: conversion, flac

I have some [ALAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Lossless) files (.m4a) that I want to convert to [FLAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAC) (.flac). How can I do this?

Comment: I tried SoundConverter but it could not convert even if I installed gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Install [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
   ```
2. Files can be converted to FLAC from ALAC via the command `ffmpeg -i audio.m4a -acodec flac audio.flac`. To do this for a while directory of files go to that directory (`cd path`) and issue the following:

   ```
   for f in *.m4a; do ffmpeg -i "$f" "${f%.m4a}.flac"; done
   ```
3. (Optional)

   - [Add replay gain to the FLAC files](https://askubuntu.com/a/106848/19490).
   - If the conversion is successful you can remove the ALAC files.

For reference see https://superuser.com/a/329278/87552 and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1500430.

Comment: What would the command be to convert to an uncompressed flac file?